# draw line between two halves of a tikz matrix easily

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m)
    [
      matrix of math nodes,
      row sep    = 3em,
      column sep = 4em
    ]
    {
      1 & 3 \\
      2 & 4\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
```

I'd like to draw a vertical line to separate the two sides of the matrix. I realize one can extend the matrix and such but I'd rather have something that is a bit more general and doesn't explicitly depend on a bunch of stuff(such as specifying nodes, extending the matrix size, computing mid points using some package, etc). (this way it works for more complex examples).

Comment: If the number of columns is even, you can simply do `\draw (m.north) -- (m.south);`. If not, have a look at my `fixed matrix` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448112/74459).

Comment: @Max If the number is even *and* the nodes have all the same widths.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443057/121799) you can find macros that do that. It is the same trick as in Zarko's answer, but done some months ago...

Comment: @marmot Oops, forgot that for a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                matrix
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m)
    [
      matrix of math nodes,
      row sep    = 3em,
      column sep = 4em
    ]
    {
      X & A \\
      Y & B\\
    };
  \draw ($(m-1-1.north east)!0.5!(m-1-2.north west)$) -- ($(m-2-1.south east)!0.5!(m-2-2.south west)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This trick has already been used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443057/121799) and perhaps before. When I wrote that answer, I couldn't find an earlier post, but that does not mean much.

Comment: @marmot, i know that i didn't discover a wheel, it  exist very long time :-). i accidentally had a little free time, so I wrote this simple answer.